# External library needs org.apache.commons.httpclient instead of org.apache.commons.http.client

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to use the Amazon Web Services Java SDK jar in an Android project in Eclipse, but it has references to *org.apache.commons.httpclient*.  All I seem to have in my Android SDK (2.2) is *org.apache.commons.http.client*, which is a different namespace and obviously causes the build to fail.

I'm new to Java, Eclipse, and Android dev... is there a way to "map" one name space to the other or create some sort of symbolic link?  If not, does that mean I have to import a "standard" org.apache.commons library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are completely different libraries. Amazon is using the older 3.x version of Jakarta Commons HttpClient, since replaced by the 4.x Apache HttpClient.

> is there a way to "map" one name space to the other or create some sort of symbolic link?

No. Particularly in this case, they are completely separate APIs. They have the same spirit, but the HttpClient folk rewrote the API significantly.

> If not, does that mean I have to import a "standard" org.apache.commons library?

Yes, and hope for the best.